# Prove that $\sigma(U \cup\{C\})=\{(A \cap C)\cup(B \cap C^\complement)| A,B \in U\}$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $U$ be a $\sigma$-Algebra ([$\sigma-algebra$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma-algebra#Definition)) and $C \subset \mathcal{P}$(power-set) gets added to $U$. How can I prove:

$$\sigma(U \cup\{C\})=\{(A \cap C)\cup(B \cap C^\complement)| A,B \in U\}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that:

$$\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \left[(A_n\cap C)\cup(B_n\cap C)\right]=\left[(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n)\cap C\right]\cup\left[(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n)\cap C\right]$$

$$\left[\left(A\cap C\right)\cup\left(B\cap C^{\complement}\right)\right]^{\complement}=\left(A^{\complement}\cap C\right)\cup\left(B^{\complement}\cap C^{\complement}\right)$$

This tells us that the collection on RHS is closed under the formation of countable unions and complements, so is a $\sigma$-algebra.

It contains $C$ as element and $\mathcal U$ as subcollection, so will contain $\sigma(\mathcal U\cup\{C\})$ as subcollection.

Conversely any $\sigma$-algebra that contains $C$ as element and $\mathcal U$ as subcollection will evidently also contain the collection on RHS.

Comment: Ist that last sentence "Conversely any σ-algebra that contains C as element and U as subcollection will evidently also contain the collection on RHS." trivial or what is the reasoning behind it? Can't see it, just started learning about this topic this week. Thanks!

Comment: Let $\mathcal A$ be a $\sigma$-algebra with $C\in\mathcal A$ and $\mathcal U\subseteq\mathcal A$. Then $C^{\complement}\in\mathcal A$ and for $A,B\in\mathcal A$ we find: $A\cap C\in\mathcal A$ and $B\cap C^{\complement}\in\mathcal A$ because a $\sigma$-algebra is closed under finite intersections. Then based on that we find $(A\cap C)\cup(B\cap C^{\complement})\in\mathcal A$ because a $\sigma$-algebra is closed under finite unions.

Comment: For being closed under finite intersections note that $A\cap C=(A^{\complement}\cup C^{\complement})^{\complement}$. For being closed under finite unions note that $A\cup C=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}D_n$ where $D_1=A$, $D_2=C$ and $D_n=\varnothing$.